# Busca usando query_args() no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou usando a seguinte query:

```
   $args = array(  
'post_type' => 'post', 
'meta_query' => array(
array(
       'key' => 'site_name',
          'value' => $busca,
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
  ),
);
query_posts($args);
```

O problema é que so retorna a busca pelo custom field "site_name". Queria que retornasse em geral tbm. Como faço?

Comment: Não entendi. Você especificou na query que quer os posts com a meta_key `site_name`, até ai ok. Que outros você quer também?

Comment: Ola, o problema é que agora so esta pesquisando pela meta_key. Quero q pesquise pelo titulo tbm!

Comment: é uma busca do site?

Comment: sim, uso  $busca = $_GET["s"];

Answer (score 0):

Essa consulta está reescrevendo a query principal e não tem como funcionar assim. Vou mostrar um outro jeito:

```
<?php // functions.php

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'busca_meta' );

function busca_meta( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_search() ) {
        return $where;
    } 

    $busca = esc_sql( get_search_query() );

    $where .= "OR ( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'site_name' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value LIKE '$busca' )";

    return $where;
}
```

Tem muita coisa acontecendo aqui então vamos com calma:

`posts_where` é o filtro por onde todas as consultas ao banco passam, onde você pode modificar a cláusula WHERE do SQL que vai ser buscado. No seu caso, como é uma busca com o parâmetro `s` o WHERE já vem setado parar buscar as palavras no titulo ou no corpo do post. O que estamos fazendo aqui é interceptar esse cláusula e adicionar uma outra ao final:

`$busca = esc_sql( get_search_query() );` é equivalente ao seu `$busca = $_GET['s']`, com a diferença que `get_search_query()` já protege o seu sistema contra caracteres ilegais que possam ter vindo na consulta. Como esse termo vai ser jogado direto no SQL adicionei também `esc_sql()` que vai terminar de escapar o termo de forma que você fique seguro contra ataques de injeção de SQL.

`$where .= "OR ...etc";` é onde a gente então acrescenta na consulta que além de buscar no titulo e conteúdo, vá buscar também na meta_key `site_name`;

Com isso quando o sistema carregar o seu arquivo `search.php` você já vai receber os resultados filtrados, sem precisar refazer a query.

ps: **[não use query_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Refer%C3%AAncia_de_Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o/query_posts)**

Comment: não testei o codigo, escrevi de cabeça. Se der erro comenta aqui que eu ajeito.